# When filling in text-input with javascript the form fails, manual typing gives no issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, forms

I'm in need of some javascript wizards....

I'm trying to autofill a form and submit with javascript in an iOS webview.
Problem is, when I do this, the form fails to submit giving username warning. When I do manual typing and submitting there is no problem. Doing it from Firefox doesn't make a difference either. Still fails to validate.

Question here is, is it possible, and if yes, how would I override this, to check if a user is doing manual input or through javascript?

I've tried using the typetype jquery library to simulate real typing, but no joy here either.

I am not in the postion to provide the link to the website here, but if you want to have a crack at it, leave me a message and I will send you the data.

Thanks!

Ron

Comment: If the user is typing manually, the onkeypress event will trigger, maybe you can use that. But have a look at the form validation code, so you can figure out why you can't fill in the field with a script.

Comment: @Shilly, thanks. Tried checking the form and field triggers but they used a JavaScript minifier, so I can't really figure out what is going on. All I can see is that both input boxes have about 12 triggers tied to them.